# Are there security concerns with migrating a sub-sub domain to a new platform, leaving another in place, and abandoning a third?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, security, security-certificate

I have been tasked with launching a website for my organization. It is a dept. within a parent organization.

- Parent Organization Administers domain.com
- Dept. Organization Administers sub.domain.com and sub.sub.domain.com

Leadership has expressed a desire to retain the same name for the new website to retain brand image and search engine traffic flow.

Old Website: sub.domain.com -> New Website: sub.domain.com

Trouble-is, in a traditional migration, all content is transferred to the website and the old website is shut down or 301 redirects put into place. In my case, most but not all content has been transferred. Specifically, content on the sub.sub.domain.

I've proposed three solutions for leadership as to what the domain name shall be:

Option A: New website retains the sub.domain.com. Old Website gets a new domain name. But everything on the sub.sub.domain.com breaks.
 - sub.sub.domain content would need to be hosted on another server with a new domain name.

Option B: New website gets a new domain name. Old Website retains the sub.domain.com. Everything on the sub.sub.domain continues to work.
 - redirects would need to be put into place so people visiting the homepage would be redirected to the new website and the new domain.

Option C: New Website retains the sub.domain.com. 
 - However, the new website web-admin would set up the sub.sub.domain according to this https://serverfault.com/questions/279403/subdomain-on-another-host-another-ip-another-provider such that the sub.sub.domain content and the links therein are not broken.

The web administrator for the sub.domain.com and sub.sub.domain.com has expressed that there will be problems for the three options but has not explicitly stated as to what these problems would be.

I've done my research and thought that a [redirect vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22925/are-open-redirects-a-security-concern) might be the problem, or that the redirect as listed in option C is not feasible for the parent organization to implement. I wanted to post this question to ProWebmasters for problems that I might not know of.

Current Content Situation

- sub1.sub.domain.com content has been successfully recreated in the new website
- sub2.sub.domain.com content isn't feasible to recreate using new website software and hosting environment, it stays where it is.
- sub3.sub.domain is being abandoned and archived until further notice.

Comment: *in a traditional migration, all content is transferred to the website and the old website is shut down or 301 redirects put into place* Not at all true. Most sites are simply replaced. If you want preserve the value of any link then you would simply redirect that URL to a relevant page.

Comment: by redirect, you are referring from the perspective of the new website correct?

Comment: Why would the old website get a new domain name?   Why introduce new domain names at all?

Comment: If the content on sub.sub.domain.com is at all valuable, option C sounds like your best optiotn to me.

Comment: The old website would need a new domain name if the current one is assigned to the new website in option A. Option B is the inverse of that. Option C is most ideal, but requires a little more legwork from web admins to configure.

Comment: I thought you were migrating all the content to the new site except the sub.sub domain

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Question has been edited to reflect content status. Some but not all content is being migrated, sub2 content is not being migrated due to technical feasibility and timescale.

Comment: An open redirect is where somebody can craft a URL that will redirect to the destination of their choosing on any other site.   Site to site redirects are usually implemented as "closed redirects" because every URL redirects to a single other domain, not to a random domain chosen by the attacker.